# Anywhere or everywhere?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

We are trying to convince people that they can use our product no matter if they are at their working place, travelling or somewhere else, so my question is how we should say it:

Protect your home from "everywhere or anywhere"!

Comment: Are you asking whether this sentence is correct or asking for a different sentence with the same meaning?

Comment: This is really off-topic as neither choice is grammatically incorrect, and both make sense. IMO, 'anywhere' sounds better (though a follow-up repeat catchphrase could then use 'everywhere'). But I have to close-vote on 'this is purely opinion' grounds.

Comment: Btw, it should be "no matter whether ..." (not no matter "if").

Comment: They are both grammatical, but they mean slightly different things. In fact, you could even say *protect your home from anywhere and everywhere* and it would actually be idiomatic, because the subtle distinction would be understood. (And because *anywhere and everywhere* is a somewhat common expression.)

Answer (score -1):

Everywhere feels out of place and over-the-top.
**Anywhere** is more suitable as per your comment.